# Is Google Drive or Firebase public folders secure from hacking?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api, public-folders

I would like to allow the users of my Android app to freely download some apks from a public folder on Google Drive, with a suitable user experience.

My concerns are about the security of this process, I mean: is Google Drive public folder something as secure as Google Play itself for apks distributing? or even as the external files that an app can officially download from its Google Play developer stuff?

If the password of the Google drive account (or maybe Firebase?) is very strong, is my idea feasible, is it secure or hackers could alter the content of the folder injecting malware?

Take into account that the public folder is also in some extent known in its existence because the app shows it.

Comment: Most important rule: nothing is 100% secure.

Comment: @Henry I know it but I would not like to facilitate hackers' job with my faults

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is unhackable but the google drive servers are pretty good protected, some informational links:

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/141702?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=1
https://tiptopsecurity.com/is-google-drive-safe-to-use/

Comment: I have edited the question, the fact is that the folder is not only public but it also publicized so it could be hacked on purpose.